# How to use Jquery ajaxSetup with Turbolinks 5

Tags: jquery, turbolinks, turbolinks-5

I'm having problem to implement Jquery ajaxSetup with Turbolinks 5

Original

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
});
```

Tried, but X-CSRF-TOKEN is not in header,

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
});
```